# set the width of a button tabBar Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tabbar

I have three tabs in my tabBar, a button icon and two texts. I want the icon to be smaller than the texts. But they are all the same width. I didn't find any property that seven this width inside tabBar.

[image]

In gray you can see what I wanted to decrease the width, is this possible?
Below is my code, where I tried to wrap the tabs in a container but I was not successful.

```
return TabBar(
  labelColor: Colors.black,
  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blue,
  indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
  tabs: [
    Container(
      color: Colors.purple,
      width: widthScreen * .10,
      child: Tab(
        icon: Icon(
          (CustomIcons.arrow_back),
          size: 30,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        width: widthScreen * .70,
        child: Tab(text: 'TEST 1')),
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: widthScreen * .70,
      child: Tab(
        text: 'TEST 2',
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `isScrollable: true,` on TabBar.

```dart
return TabBar(
  isScrollable: true, //this
  labelColor: Colors.black,
  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blue,
  indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for what I wanted.

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore about [TabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html)